# CSS transition disturbs the whole page

Tags: html, css

i put some social icons in site, when i hover the circle around it gets bigger.
which is fine by me. but the problem i am facing is that when that div gets bigger, it disturbs the other divs. i tried z-index but dont know why its not working..

Here is the site which i uploaded for the sake for fixing it..

http://muntazir.mmellahi.com/Muntazir%20prosmatic%20demo%202/

Can anyone help me fix the issue so that if the circle goes big, it do not disturb other divs.

if you open page and mouse over the social icon on heading you will notice the gallery will go down a bit but when you remove the cursor the gallery will come back to its place.

sorry for the poor explanation..

update : Adding Code.

**CSS** i used for social Icons

```
    .headerSocialIcons{
    float: right;
    margin-top: -44px;
    width: 100%;
}


.headerSocialIcons .SocialIcons{
    width: 100%;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.headerSocialIcons .SocialIcons .link{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    position: relative;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    border: 2px dashed white;
    background-clip: content-box;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: .5s;
    color: #D7D0BE;
    margin-left: 15px;
    margin-right: 15px;
    text-shadow:
        0 -1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2),
        0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    font-size: 28px;
}

.headerSocialIcons .SocialIcons .link span{
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
.headerSocialIcons .SocialIcons .link:hover{
    padding: 20px;
    color: white;
    margin-left: -5px;
    transform: translateX(10px) rotate(360deg);
}

.headerSocialIcons .SocialIcons .link.google-plus {
    background-color: tomato;
    color: white;
}

.headerSocialIcons .SocialIcons .link.twitter {
    background-color: #00ACEE;
    color: white;
}

.headerSocialIcons .SocialIcons .link.facebook {
    background-color: #3B5998;
    color: white;
}

.headerSocialIcons .SocialIcons a{
    width: 35px;
    height: 35px;
    display: inline-block;
    border-radius: 5px;
    font-family: "scicons";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    transition: background-color .2s linear, color .2s linear;
}
.headerSocialIcons .Left{
    display: inline;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 350px;

}
.headerSocialIcons .Right{
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    text-align: right;
    width: 350px;

}
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="headerSocialIcons">
    <div class="SocialIcons Left">
        <a href="#" class="link facebook" target="_parent"><span class="fa fa-facebook-square"></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="link twitter" target="_parent"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="link google-plus" target="_parent"><span class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></span></a>
    </div>
    <div class="SocialIcons Right">
        <a href="#" class="link facebook" target="_parent"><span class="fa fa-facebook-square"></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="link twitter" target="_parent"><span class="fa fa-twitter"></span></a>
        <a href="#" class="link google-plus" target="_parent"><span class="fa fa-google-plus-square"></span></a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Where is the code that you're having problems with?

Comment: Questions should be self-contained; when you fix the problem on your site this question will be worthless to others. Furthermore, we're not going to look through your *entire* website's code to find your exact problem; post the specific code in which there's a problem, with a minimal working example to reproduce the issue.

Comment: @Doorknob
Thankyou sir for Explaining me, i didn't thought of that way. I added both CSS and HTML code which i used for social icons.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

problem solved.
i had to use `position:relative` with `z-index`. 
thankyou.